# Facing error while sending multiple values from anchor tag to controller in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

i am trying to send multiple values from anchor tag of thymleaf to controller. I am not sure how to send multiple values and to accept it in the ModelAttribute as object

**thymleaf code:**

```
<a th:href="@{/frontView(id1=${1})(id2=${2})}">Home</a>
```

**controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/frontView")
    public void FrontView(@ModelAttribute Model m) {
        
    }
```

**error:**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are sending 2 values from the anchor tag in the wrong way do something like

```
<a th:href="@{/frontView/(id1=${1},id2=${2})}">home</a>
```

Or

**for Path varibales**

```
 <a th:href="@{/frontView/{id1}/{id2} (id1=${1},id2=${2})}">home</a>
```

Then change your controller. Remove @ModelAttribute as it take an object and you are sending 2 values hence use @RequestParam or @PathVariable

```
@GetMapping("/frontView")
public void FrontView(@RequestParam("id1")int id1,@RequestParam("id2")int id2) {
        
}
```

Comment: I've only used Thymleaf a little bit, so forgive what might be a naive question...can you explain what your example 'a' tags are doing?  Neither of them seems obvious to me.  For the first one, is the bit in parens going to become a query string portion of the URL?  For the second one, the params are clearly path parameters, but what does the bit in parens do in that case?  (I assume that in the second case, that's just how Thym works. The first one's more of a puzzler for me.)

Comment: The second one will send request with path variables as `http://localhost:8080/frontView/1/2?id1=1&id2=2 `
Which will not help in the question's case as they want to receive parameters

Comment: its working with RequestParam, thanks